# Saving an image bmp c#

Tags: c#, image, save, bmp

I have this function that draw an image in bmp format

```
private void DrawImage(Byte[] imgData, PictureBox picBox)
  {
     int colorval;
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(m_ImageWidth, m_ImageHeight);
     picBox.Image = (Image)bmp;

     for (int i=0; i<bmp.Width; i++)
     {
        for (int j=0; j<bmp.Height; j++)
        {
           colorval = (int)imgData[(j*m_ImageWidth)+ i];
           bmp.SetPixel(i,j,Color.FromArgb(colorval,colorval, colorval));
        }
     }
     picBox.Refresh();

    }
```

When i add `picBox.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Jose Moreno\Desktop", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);`

below PicBox.Refresh();, the program crash with the errror: 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"

Why the program crash? thatks for the help.

Comment: What about `filename`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Image.Save(String, ImageFormat)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) requires the full **filename**, not just the **file path**.  `"C:\Users\Jose Moreno\Desktop"` is (presumably) the name of a pre-existing directory, not the name of a file that could be created.  You need to pass an actual file name, for instance:

```
picBox.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Jose Moreno\Desktop\TestFilename.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

If a file of the specified name cannot be created, you will get this inscrutable error.

Note that if the image was originally loaded from a file, you cannot save back to the same file until the image is disposed of because the file gets locked.  See [How can I fix this GDI+ generic exception when I save images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010789/how-can-i-fix-this-gdi-generic-exception-when-i-save-images).  But that's not the problem shown in your question.